# Encoding in admin aread created with CRUD

Tags: playframework

I have a problem with the admin area I created with CRUD. I've set pretty much everything possible to UTF-8 yet I still have a problem with getting correct (polish) characters in fields such as ł, ó, ż, ć, ą etc. (i get '?' instead). Same happens for initial-data.yml. If I manually save something in database then it displays properly, which seems like a CRUD -> database communication issue.  Encoding works properly on not-autogenerated pages. I've set all files in crud folder to UTF-8. Any ideas? Help please.

Using play ver. 1.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Play uses only one encoding, namely UTF-8, as they declare it themselves: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/i18n

This means that you should normally use an UTF-8 encoded database as well, so that whatever you save there from your play application keeps the proper characters in the db as well. Make sure your db is UTF-8 encoded aswell. Also make sure that you haven't manually changed your views (html pages) encoding to something else other then UTF-8

Comment: Problem is that my database is in UTF-8 and all the files I got in Eclipse project I've changed to UTF-8 and checked twice. Got no idea where the problem lies.

Comment: This is very strange. I've just tried it now, created a Play project, very basic no extra setup. Imported in Eclipe (not as UTF-8, i left the default Eclipse encoding ISO-whatever). Saved some data to postgre UTF-8 database, then redisplay it, all with the Play app, special french characters (such as é) are displayed fine. I'm on windows 7 ultimate french edition. I'm honestlly stumped, this should work ok. Try posing the question to the Play guys (on the site or forum)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with play 1.2.1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with connection to MySQL. You should add

```
?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8
```

to your database url. For example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8
```